# How to list only sub-diectories of a directory in julia?

Tags: filesystems, julia

i tried to list the directories in a directory, /path/to/parent/folder, as below:

```
parent_dir ="/path/to/parent/folder"
dirs = filter(x -> isdir(x), readdir(parent_dir))

for dir in dirs
println(dir)
end
```

but prints nothing!

Please help me listing only sub-directories of a parent direcory!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that your current working directory `pwd()` is not the same as `parent_dir`?

`readdir(parent_dir)` results in a list of entries, e.g. just the name, not the full path, and when you call `isdir(x)` Julia works relative the current working directory. What you probably want to do is something like:

```
parent_dir ="/path/to/parent/folder"
dirs = filter(x -> isdir(joinpath(parent_dir, x)), readdir(parent_dir))

for dir in dirs
    println(dir)
end
```

e.g. prepend `x` with the folder that you read it from with `joinpath`.

---

Since Julia version 1.4 you can use use the `join` keyword argument to `readdir`, which gives you the full paths directly:

```
parent_dir ="/path/to/parent/folder"
dirs = filter(isdir, readdir(parent_dir; join=true))
```

Comment: If you need the full paths of the subdirectories you can also do
`subdirs = readdir(isdir, parent_dir, join=true)`.
In case that you also need the directory names you can use `basename.(subdirs)`

Comment: Yes, since Julia version 1.4 you can use the `join` keyword. Wasn't released at the time of answering.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `readdir`, you can check out `walkdir` which lets you do a lot more. It produces an iterator that traverses the directory tree below a given folder. For your particular usecase the code would look like this:

```
parent_dir ="/path/to/parent/folder"
dirs = first(walkdir(parent_dir))[2]
```

It is approximately as fast as the `filter`/`readdir` approach, perhaps slightly slower, but it has a lot of other uses.

Comment: bit explanation on first() please! depth or what it is! I guess element at index 1, 2, 3 are parent directory, directories and files.  please correct me if i am wrong!

Comment: The function `first` is similar to getting index number 1. `walkdir` returns an iterator that cannot be indexed directly into, you have to ask for the first element by calling `first` instead. You can also use `first` on indexable collections, if you like. Concerning the meaning of indices 1,2,3, you are correct.